# How to solve queryIntentActivities deprecated in API 33

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

I am getting a strange behavior in Android Studio with API33. In the following code,

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, filename);
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(chooser, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

I am getting `queryIntentActivities(Intent,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated`.

In the docs, it says: **This method was deprecated in API level 33.** `Use queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent, android.content.pm.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags) instead.`

I tried changing `Intent` with `android.content.Intent`, but get the same problem. `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` is one of the possible flag values, so I do not understand what this error is trying to tell me...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your current call is:

```java
queryIntentActivities(chooser, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
```

Here, `chooser` is an `Intent`, and `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` is an `int`.

That matches [the deprecated `queryIntentActivities()` version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

On API Level 33 and higher devices, Google would like you to use [the `queryIntentActivities()` version that takes a `ResolveInfoFlags` as the second parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags)), instead of an `int`. You would [use `ResolveInfoFlags.of()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags#of(long)) to wrap `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` into a `ResolveInfoFlags` object.

That method will not be available on API Level 32 and older devices, so your choices are:

- Stick with the `int` one, despite the deprecation, or
- Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine the API level and call the desired version of `queryIntentActivities()` based on the API level of the device

Comment: Great. The `ResolveInfoFlags.of()` thing is what I was missing, I didn't know about that. Yet, besides the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` I had to add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`...

Answer (score 15):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER),
            PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong())
        )
    } else {
        context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER),
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
        )
    }
```

Comment: Why is bottom condition deprecated?

Comment: @AlexS The original parameters included flags, which translate to an integer. The new parameters include `ResolveInfoFlags`, which translate to a long. 

It honestly reads like an attempt to inline documenting what the parameter means without actually having to write documentation (Google often struggles to write competent usage documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can cast PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY into long.
Something like this:

```
queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to pass InfoFlag as second parameter and not an int. [Here you can find list of the flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags) and from there you can check what each one is for so you can use it for your example
So the solution would look something like

```
queryIntentActivities(chooser, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
```

Comment: No, this is what I did already, and does not solve the problem. After all, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY = 65536 is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Fulfill common use cases while having limited package visibility

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases

add queries in manifest

```html
<manifest>
.....
.....
<queries>
    <!-- Browser -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
     </intent>

     <!--For external application-->
     <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
.....
.....
</manifest>
```